# How to copy data from an object row into another object row from the same class in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been searching online but I had no luck to get the best way to do this.

I have a controller, in that controller I execute a sql query to retrieve all requests from a user

```
    @solicitudes = Solicitud.where("user_id = ?",@current_user.id)
```

And I want to know how to transfer each data row on the main object to the proper object with all requests with the same status. I have tried:

```
    @solicitudes.each do |solicitud|
           if solicitud.estado == 1
             @solicitudes_pendientes << solicitud
           else
             if solicitud.estado == 2
               @solicitudes_aprobadas << solicitud
             else
               if solicitud.estado == 3
                 @solicitudes_rechazadas << solicitud
               end
             end
          end
     end
```

But clearly is not working.

At the moment I am using 3 sql queries to retrieve all requests into their corresponding objects but that takes 3 x time + 2 extra transactions:

```
@solicitudes_pendientes = Solicitud.where("estado = 1 and user_id = ?",@current_aplicante.id)


    @solicitudes_aprobadas = Solicitud.where("estado = 2 and user_id = ?",@current_aplicante.id)


    @solicitudes_rechazadas = Solicitud.where("estado = 3 and user_id = ?",@current_aplicante.id)
```

Waiting for any useful advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

```
 @solicitudes = Solicitud.where(:user_id => @current_user.id).entries.group_by(&:estado)
```

which will give you a Hash of the form

```
  {
    1 => [#<Solicitud estado: 1>, #<Solicitud estado: 1>],
    2 => [#<Solicitud estado: 2>, #<Solicitud estado: 2>, ..],
    3 => ..,
    ..
  }
```

You can access them like

```
@solicitudes_pendientes = @solicitudes[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Santosh, at the moment I am using @ solicitudes_pendientes.each do |solicitud| but now it gives a nil class error. Could you please adivse which would be the best approach @Santosh